# Dovecot users have no file permissions

Tags: linux, ldap, dovecot

I want to authenticate dovecot against LDAP (AD based on Samba 4).
The files are stored in /var/mail/vmail/, which is owned by vmail:vmail . One user is working, since it uses vmail as uid and gid:

```
$ sudo doveadm user du
field   value
uid vmail
gid vmail
home    
mail    maildir:/var/mail/vmail//du
```

All other user can't change the directory (and therefore store no mails), they look like this:

```
$ sudo doveadm user sh
field   value
uid 2035
gid 5074
home    
mail    maildir:/var/mail/vmail//sh
```

I have no idea, why this user does not use vmail as virtual user to change the maildir.

The relevant configs look like this:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_uid = vmail
mail_gid = vmail
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.key
login_log_format_elements = "user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l mpid=%e %c %k"
mail_plugins = quota
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
ssl_cipher_list = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
protocols = imap
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth_dovecot {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = root
}
service dict {
    unix_listener dict {
        mode = 0660
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
    }
}
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota
}
plugin {
  quota = maildir:User quota
}
```

And the Dovecot LDAP:

```
uris = ldaps://ucs01.domain.tld 
dn = cn=ldap-read,ou=Users,ou=domain,dc=domain,dc=tld
dnpass = ***********
tls_ca_cert_dir = /etc/ssl/certs/
tls_require_cert = never
auth_bind = yes
ldap_version = 3
base = ou=domain,dc=domain,dc=tld
scope = subtree
user_filter = (sAMAccountName=%Ln)
pass_filter = (sAMAccountName=%Ln)
iterate_attrs = uid=user
iterate_filter = (objectClass=person)
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
```

Comment: Maybe try to add rest of the users to the same group as vmail?

Comment: @AvivLo To do that, I have to create the users at the dovecot server and add them to the vmail group. It may work, but does not scale and is not the basic idea behind the ldap auth.

Comment: But ldap auth is ldap auth. Linux permission is another thing.

Comment: I use sql based auth, with very similar settings to what you posted. 2 differences: I have `mail_privileged_group` set to `vmail`, and I store my mail in `/srv/vmail`. Maybe try adding `mail_privileged_group=vmail` to your config? And moving your mail to `/srv/vmail` would let you limit how many directories your vmail user needs permissions to browse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be common to fetch numerical uid and numerical gid for dovecot's virtual user's `home` and `maildir`s from the LDAP directory. That said and since you do not have a prefetch setup, user/group information should be obtained incorporating `user_filter` and `user_attrs` from `dovecot-ldap.conf.ext`.

I can only speculate, but I can't find neither `user_attrs` nor `pass_attrs` in your `dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` file and since dovecot's example configuration files usually contain the default settings, I had a look at [dovecot-ldap.conf.ext](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/master/doc/example-config/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext) from the offical github repo. It turns out, there it contains a numerical uid and gid mapping. Here goes, last line of snippet.

```
# User attributes are given in LDAP-name=dovecot-internal-name list. The
# internal names are:
#   uid - System UID
#   gid - System GID
#   home - Home directory
#   mail - Mail location
#
# There are also other special fields which can be returned, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase/ExtraFields
#user_attrs = homeDirectory=home,uidNumber=uid,gidNumber=gid
```

So now on to the interesting part: do you happen to have attributes `uidNumber` and `gidNumber` on your LDAP entities, that you query (usually some `person` or `account` objectClass)? If so, please check if the uid/gid values you observed in dovecot's vmail folder correspond to the values stored in LDAP.